# How do I disable a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEMO_DBLEVELTRIGGER
ON DATABASE
AFTER CREATE_TABLE
AS
BEGIN
PRINT 'CREATION OF NEW TABLES NOT ALLOWED'
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
GO
```

Comment: If you are not the admin who created it, then you don't period.

Comment: You're probably looking for a `DROP TRIGGER DEMO_DBLEVELTRIGGER;`

Comment: Sounds to me like someone doesn't want the creation of new tables to be allowed...

Comment: I made the trigger myself as I am learning about them. The course that I have taken however doesn't explain how to disable them. I also have admin rights and, when I execute DROP TRIGGER DEMO_DBLEVELTRIGGER, the trigger is still not deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is a database level trigger and you want to disable specifically one trigger then use

```
DISABLE TRIGGER triggername ON DATABASE;  
GO
```

if it is a database level trigger and you want to disable all triggers on one table, then use

```
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON schemaname.tablename;
GO
```

if it is a database level trigger and you want to disable all the triggers in that particular database,  then use

```
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON DATABASE;  
GO
```

If trigger has server scope then use below

```
DISABLE TRIGGER triggername ON ALL SERVER
```

If you want to disable all triggers which have server scope,then use

```
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON ALL SERVER
```

you have to use `ALL` with caution ..Docs state..

> SQL Server creates triggers in databases that are published for merge replication. Specifying ALL in published databases disables these triggers, which disrupts replication. Verify that the current database is not published for merge replication before specifying ALL.

**NOTE:**
Changing the trigger by using the ALTER TRIGGER statement enables the trigger

**References:**
[DISABLE TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql)

Comment: DISABLE TRIGGER DEMO_DBLEVELTRIGGER ON AdventureWorks2012;
GO

The error I get is, "Cannot find the object "AdventureWorks2012" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Database level trigger, you have to specify that you're dropping the trigger *on the database*.

so instead of...

```
drop trigger DEMO_DBLEVELTRIGGER
```

do

```
drop trigger DEMO_DBLEVELTRIGGER on database
```

of course from the context of whatever database you created it on.

Comment: He want to disable, not to drop it.

Comment: He mentioned dropping it in his comment on the OP. Wisdow still holds; just replace `drop` with `disable` if that's what you want.